# JNA pointer to store file handle

Tags: c, jna, spss

I'm using JNA to use a .dll in Java.

The method i'm trying to use is this (in C):

```
int fH; /* file handle */
int error; /* error code */
error = spssOpenWrite("mydata.sav", &fH);
```

It creates a new file and stores the file handle in hFile and returns an error code.
I'm not sure how to recreate that with JNA, i tried using the pointer-object like this:

```
Pointer fH = new Memory(4096);
int error = 0;
error = CLibrary.INSTANCE.spssOpenWrite("mydata.sav", fH);
```

But that doesn't change the value of fH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "value" of `fH` would be the same memory address that you originally defined.  If you attempted to read that value, however, you should get the result, e.g., `fH.getInt(0)`.

However, allocating 4096 bytes to hold an integer is overkill.  Why not just use the `IntByReference` class designed specifically for this purpose?

```
int fH; /* file handle */
int error; /* error code */
IntByReference pFH = new IntByReference(); // allocates memory for the int
error = CLibrary.INSTANCE.spssOpenWrite("mydata.sav", pFH);
// TODO: test error value before proceeding
fH = pFH.getValue();
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it. I tried IntByReference, since i thought that would be the right idea, but did not try just setting that value to an integer and work with that.